# A function with C strings that never return

Tags: c, string, malloc, strtok

I'm new here. I have a problem and I have absolutely no idea of what cause it!
I hope someone could help me.
I'm developing a little TCP server with socket that receive a string from clients and have to do some stuff on it.
The program stay blocked in this function, that never return:

```
int parse_request(char * request, char *start, char**headers, char *body)
```

The core of the function is a combination of 2 nested strtok():

```
line = strtok_r (request, "\n", &saveptr1);
while (line != NULL) {

    if (strcmp(line, "\r\n") == 0 || strcmp(line, "\r") == 0) bdy = 1;
    else {
        if (i == 1) {
            /* the first line (command) */
            printf("linea iniziale: ");
            start = line;
            start[strlen(line)] = '\0';
            printf ("%s\n",start);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            if (bdy == 0) {
                /* the headers */
                temp = line;
                subline = strtok_r (temp, ":", &saveptr2);
                head = subline;
                head[strlen(subline)] = '\0';
                subline = strtok_r (NULL, ":", &saveptr2);
                if (subline != NULL) {
                    value = subline;
                    value[strlen(subline)] = '\0';
                    }
                else value = "none";

                if (strcmp(head, "Connection") == 0 && strcmp(value, "close") == 0) retval = 0;
                if (strcmp(head, "Content-Length") == 0) ignoreboby = 0;

                headers[j] = head;
                headers[j+1] = value;
                printf("header -> %s : %s\n", headers[j], headers[j+1]);
                j = j + 2;
            }
            else {
                headers[j] = '\0';
                if (ignoreboby != 1){
                    /* the body */
                    printf("body: ");
                    body = line;
                    body[strlen(line)] = '\0';
                    printf ("%s\n",body);
                }
                else {
                    body = "\0";
                    **printf("body ignored\n");**
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("kkk");
    line = strtok_r (NULL, "\n", &saveptr1);
    i++;
}
```

The program blocks just after printing "body ignored" or "Body: %s\n, body".

Someone has an idea? I'm really in troubles!
Thanks

EDIT: Could it be the way I create and pass the arguments the real problem?

```
char command[] = "\0", body[] = "\0";
char **headers;
headers = malloc(8192);
        if (!headers) {
            printf("Error in malloc()");
            closesocket(s);
        }
int x = parse_request(buf, command, headers, body);
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the problem, but the lines of code of the form  `body[strlen(line)] = '\0';` are not necessary as it is currently written.  body and line point to the same memory and strlen is effectively returning the position of the null terminator, so the assignment as no affect (because body == line).

Comment: You're right! I removed those not necessary statements.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you expect people to look for more than trivial syntax problems.  As it stands, it might be a problem with a non-NUL terminated input string, or there might be something odd in the input you're not considering.

Comment: With the way you are passing the arguments, `command` and `body` are INPUTS to the function and changes made to the local `start` and `body` inside the function will have no effect on the variables used to pass in the values...

Comment: Guys I want to thank you all for your help. I found the point: I was supposing that the code was blocked cause it stopped to print his output but now I realized that the problem was the stdout buffer!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't change `line` so you're stuck in the `while` loop.

Comment: Look again. The assignment `line = strtok_r (NULL, "\n", &saveptr1);` is inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Line is changed every loop. The problem is only in the last loop (usually after 6-7 times). Maybe the exit condition is never reached but I really don't know why.